# data according to date

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, date

i have data like this

```
compnay         employee    service_start_Date  service_end_Date   service_status
abc company     david       01/01/2017          1/1/1900            in_service
abc comapny     john        12/02/2016          1/1/1900            in_service
defcompany      abc_1       05/12/2011          12/02/2017          regisned
ghgcompany      rock        02/11/2009          04/03/2017          terminated
abc company1    david1      01/01/2017          1/1/1900            in_service
abc company     david2      01/01/2017          1/1/1900            in_service
abc company2    david3      01/01/2017          1/1/1900            in_service
abc company     david4      01/01/2015          1/1/2017            in_service
abc company2    david5      01/01/2017          1/1/1900            in_service
```

...... and so many data like this

here when employee did not resign /terminated/expired then by default date is set like this 1/1/1900
where as when employee resigned/termindate/expired then service_end_date is marked so i want data 
like how many employees joined and leave according to month and year
like this

if i select parameter month 1 and year 2017 then this show like this

```
company          joiners  leavers
abc company         3        1
abc company1        3        0
```

when i select  like    month 5 and year 2011 then this shows like this

```
company    joiners  leavers
defcompany  1        0
```

i tried this

```
select  e.company,count(e.EmployeeIndex) joiners,count(e.EmployeeIndex) leavers
            from    emp_table e 
            where                   

                     service_end_Date between 
                    convert(datetime,rtrim(convert(char,@FromDate,101)),101) 
                     and  convert(datetime,rtrim(convert(char,@ToDate,101)),101) 

                     and service_start_Date between 
                    convert(datetime,rtrim(convert(char,@FromDate,101)),101) 
                     and  convert(datetime,rtrim(convert(char,@ToDate,101)),101) 
        group by e.company

    this query did not show correct data..
```

Comment: What datatype in the database are service_start_date and service_end_date? Also what are you passing through as FromDate and ToDate parameters in the failed query?

Comment: datetime... i pass like this if i want to get data only jan then  fromdate '01/01/2017' , todate '01/30/2017'

Answer (score 0):

Your current query is counting the same thing twice for both joiners and leavers. You need to move the check up to the select area for those columns. This is the basic idea

```
select  e.company,
    SUM(case when service_start_date between @FromDate and @ToDate then 1 else 0 end) as joiners
    , SUM(case when service_end_date between @FromDate and @ToDAte then 1 else 0 end) as leavers

from    emp_table e 
        where                   
            service_end_Date between @FromDate and @ToDate
        OR --not AND
            service_start_Date between @FromDate and @ToDate
group by e.company
```

You can leave the whole bottom where clause off and it will still work, but it will also return all companies even if both the numbers are zero (this may be wanted or not).

Comment: Because we use case to set a flag to 1 for the valid rows, and zero for the invalid rows, you need to sum the numbers. If you use count, you will just get the number of rows you checked, not the number that are valid

Comment: what when i use count on e.employee ?

Comment: this shows something wrong when i check randomly in table like when i use this select * from emp_table where company_id=850 and ServiceStatus=1 
and  service_start_date between '01/01/2017' and '01/30/2017' then this shows only 1 in_Service employee where as when i use your query and check then this shows 2 joiners mean in_Service employee in that date period

Comment: What does ServiceStatus have to do with it? You never mentioned or used it before in the query

Comment: ok if use servicestatus='in_Service' then this shows same as mentioned..

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this using below query:

```
SELECT *
 FROM (
  SELECT employee, compnay
  ,Case when year(service_end_Date) = 1900 then
  'joiners'
  else 
  'leavers' end as Company_Year
  FROM [emp_table] 
  -- where  year(service_start_Date) = 2011  and month(service_start_Date) = 5
 ) as s
 PIVOT
 (
  count(employee)
  FOR [Company_Year] IN (joiners,leavers)
 )AS pvt;
```

Comment: this shows total .. where as i want according to company

Comment: and why you count on companyname.. i need count on e.employee.. i am counting employees not companies..

Comment: @see sharp, I have updated query to show total employee company wise